# Getting Redshift error 1214 during copy

Tags: redshift

I have the following table in redshift:

```
 Column | Type
 id       integer
 value    varchar(255)
```

I'm trying to copy in (using the datapipeline's RedshiftCopyActivity), and the data has the line `1,maybe` as the entry trying to be added, but I get back the error 1214:Delimiter not found, and the raw_field_data value is `maybe`.  Is there something I'm missing in the copy parameters?

The entire csv is three lines that goes:

```
1,maybe
2,no
3,yes
```

Comment: please look at the link bellow seems like the same issue:
[redshift copy command error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862727/redshift-copy-command-delimiter-not-found)

Comment: @GilDeWinter not really, when I ran that query it kind of scrambled the messages and got better errors from "select * from stl_load_error"